# Changing hostname for remote login on a Mac

Tags: macos, hostname

I would like to change the hostname of my Mac for when I want to SCP or SSH into my computer.

I followed instructions to change my hostname online using [`scutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html). Now when I enter `hostname` into terminal it echoes what I changed it to. However, when I go to “System Preference > Sharing” and I enable remote login it shows a different hostname that is derived from my IP address and the provider of my wifi (like `my_ip_address.dhcp4.some_university.edu`).

How can I change the computer specific part of my hostname (the IP address part) to always be the same thing regardless of the DNS part of the hostname?

Also, I am being shown two different hostnames. What are the differences between the two, and how does the hostname that I was able to change come into play?

EDIT:
I've changed my HostName, ComputerName and my LocalHostName as instructed by Giacomo1968, and I still have this problem. When I query terminal for my hostname it returns the value I changed it to with [`scutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html), however, when I enable file sharing in the sharing section of System Preferences I get some iteration of my IP address paired with the DNS of the internet provider. This is true regardless of the internet provider.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly did you set the hostname via [`scutil`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/scutil.8.html)? Generally if you run this command your hostname should be solid and unalterable by a remote DHCP server; of course change `yourHostName` to be your desired hostname:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
```

If you want to be thorough, be sure to set the `ComputerName`, `HostName` and `LocalHostName` as well like this:

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName 'yourHostName'
sudo scutil --set HostName 'yourHostName'
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName  'yourHostName'
```

When those are set you can double-check the new values using the `--get` option of `scutil` like this:

```
scutil --get ComputerName
scutil --get HostName
scutil --get LocalHostName
```

Comment: I had done `sudo scutil --set HostName 'myHostName'`, but just to be sure I also changed my computer name and local hostname as you suggested. However, the hostname when I enable remote login in System Preferences hasn't changed.